# Nginx redirect https www to https non-www

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I have SSL cert to my domain `mydomain.com` (without `www.`)
Nginx config:

```
server
{
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

All redirects work fine except `https://www.mydomain.com` -> `https://mydomain.com`.
Every browser show me an alert with message like this:

```
    This Connection is Untrusted

    You have asked Firefox to connect securely to www.mydomain.com, 
but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you certificate `https://mydomain.com`?

Comment: Yes, I have certificate for `https://mydomain.com`

Comment: ...and `https://www.mydomain.com` too ?

Comment: Are you using a redirect on `mydomain.com`? That's likely the problem - the redirect that begins at `mydomain.com` occurs over HTTP, not HTTPS. Also, use `example.com`, not `mydomain.com`. IANA reserves it for that purpose.

Comment: no, I haven't certificate for `www.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. HTTPS is HTTP inside SSL, so to get the HTTP redirect first the SSL connection has to be established and verified - and this is the steps where it fails if you don't use a certificate not trusted by the browser (e.g. self-signed or where the hostname does not match the certificate).